# 301 error randomly happening for python cgi file request

Tags: apache, http, redirect

I have a URL which sometimes fails to resolve and kicks me back to its parent directory. So I type this:

`www.mysite.com/hub/parent/mycgi.cgi`

... and get sent here instead:

`www.mysite.com/hub/parent/`

The `parent` dir in my file system has an index.cgi page that ends up showing, and this `index.cgi` has the exact same stats and permissions as `mycgi`. 775 and the group/owner are the same.

This problem is hard to reproduce, but some combination of logging in and out while incognito, then trying the URL in the browser causes the issue. I don't see anything in my httpd/error_log, but in the access log I can see:

```
<internal proxy IP> - - [10/May/2017:11:52:41 -0700] "GET /hub/parent/mycgi.cgi? HTTP/1.1" 301 236 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck..."
```

I also see this (sometimes) when I add a `?`:

```
<internal proxy IP> - - [10/May/2017:11:35:58 -0700] "GET /hub/parent/mycgi.cgi? HTTP/1.1" 301 236 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck..."
```

I know that 301 means "Moved Permanently", but these files are not moving... How is this possible and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't mean the file has moved -- just that you are permanently redirecting one URL to another.  The answer is in the code inside mycgi.cgi -- it might be responding 301.  Or you might have something in your apache config that does it based on the request.  Try testing with the ? at the end.

Comment: It happens at random. The contents of the file, and the configuration of apache would not explain this since it is random. It sometimes happens with the ? and sometimes it happens without the ?.